# Error on command: service: “ecmascript”

Tags: webdriver

I have sucessfully run locator commands in Firefox, Chrome and IE but I have an issue with **Opera 12.02**.
This code is the source of the issue:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_txtUserLog")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
//entering values to a username field
```

I got the following error in console:

```
com.opera.core.systems.scope.exceptions.CommunicationException: Error on command:
service: "ecmascript" commandID: 2 format: 0status:tag: 32 payload: "\n%Unknown error while executing command"
```

I am newbie to Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: You have also posted the same questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489609/error-on-command-service-ecmascript.  Not sure posting in multiple forums will help more.  A few people answering here and a few there will segment the information for anyone looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the last section on this page addresses a similar(?) problem as a known issue:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver

Also, it says the Opera 12.00+ is not yet officially supported by selenium OperaDriver